# What exactly is a search space?

Tags: ai.artificial-intel, search-problem

I am new to CS so excuse my question if it seems very rudimentary.

I just want to make sure I understand the terminology 100% correct as I go along. Is a "search space" the total amount of all the possible states that may lead up to a successful goal or is the "search space" only all the possible states reachable from the current state?

Comment: [about], [help/on-topic]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

'search space' is indeed the set of all possible states.
the set of all possible states reachable from the initial state are called 'successor functions'.

are you teaching yourself?

Comment: Hi Aldreezy, thanks for the answer. Yes I am teaching myself. I am enrolled in a long distance University so I prefer to search for answers to questions I am not 100% sure on, on the internet as asking a lecturer via email can take a few days.